one of two garage lights always on
I have two ceiling garage lights.  Only 1 turns off with the switch; the other stays on all the time.  There are 2 switches for the lights; one in the kitchen and one in the garage.  Only one of the lights turns on and off with the switches.  What's the likely problem here?

Miswiring, or you havent found the switch for it.

There are two possibilities that come to mind:
Missing Switch
There is another switch somewhere in the garage for the 2nd light. Either that switch is hidden, e.g., behind a cabinet or something, or it used to exist and was disconnected with the light left "always on", or some rewiring was done resulting in the switch not having any effect on the light and it is now "always on".
Rewiring
Both lights used to be controlled together by the switches. At some point somebody did some work on wiring, perhaps fixing or replacing the 2nd light fixture, and rewired things in a way that the 2nd light was no longer controlled by the switch.
The only way to figure out what is wrong and how to fix it is to get pictures showing the wiring (a) at the garage switch (kitchen switch is not likely relevant) and (b) above each light fixture.
